# sphinx. Работа с пробелами

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch, sphinxapi

Всем привет! Как настроить работу sphinx так, чтобы он не воспринимал пробелы между словами как логическое "и". То есть если человек вводит "наступила зима", осуществлялся поиск строго этого словосочетания. 
То есть результаты типа: `....наступила зима....`
а не: `... наступила.........зима....`

Comment: Обычно это решается синтаксисом поискового запроса: `наступила зима`  — это поиск текста, в котором встречаются оба слова, а `"наступила зима"` — поиск точного соответствия.

Comment: Т.е. если зафорсить такое поведение, как вы хотите, вы можете сделать неудобно пользователю, который захочет поискать `зима лыжи санки`.

Comment: Nick Volynkin, то есть нужно просто поставить в кавычки? Тут такой случай, что пользователи не хотят получать кучу лишней мусорной информации, нерелевантной. они хотят строгого соответствия

Comment: для поиска точного соответствия можно было бы обойтись без сфинкса..

Comment: vp_arth, например? у меня в таблице 18 млн записей, myisam. Надо чтобы было быстро при этом. Поиск осуществляется по полю content, через like '%%',  индексировать невозможно

Comment: @Baurzhan ну ладно, вам видней, вы своих пользователей лучше знаете. )